# C# WPF node traversing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button like this:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="10">
    <Button.Content>
        <Viewbox>
            <Label Name="Option1">Hello</Label>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

And I want to get it's content (Hello). I have previously used

```
 (e.Source as Button).Content.ToString()
```

And it gave me the content of the button if it was only some value, but now there's a viewbox and a label so it doesn't work. Can I do something like (e.Source as Button).Content.Viewbox.Label.Content() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do it like:

```
(((e.Source as Button).Content as Viewbox).Child as Label).Content
```

But it should still work.

Also note that since you're using 'safe casting' with the `as` keyword, at any point you could run into a `null` which would throw an NRE.  So you might want to be a bit more verbose like:

```
Button b = e.Source as Button;
if(b != null) {
   Viewbox v = b.Content as Viewbox;

   // .. etc
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning null checks. Nothing I hate more than NullReferenceExceptions

Comment: Hm, I get this error "Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I tried casting without viewbox but then application crashed.

Comment: Try the `Child` property instead.  I've not used the `Viewbox` myself so I was basing my code sample on what you had written.  But I think the `Child` property is the appropriate property.

Comment: Oh, nvm, I just put Label in Viewbox.Child and now it works.
EDIT: oh haha, that's what I did :)

Comment: So was it `.Child`, I want to make sure my code sample is accurate for future reference. =)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to cast Button.Content as Viewbox, then Viewbox.Content as Label, then cast the Label.Content to a string

Answer (score 0):

Don't even try to do it like that... Sure, it *is* possible, but it's painful and error-prone. Use a `DataTemplate` instead:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" Content="Hello">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

The way the button content is presented is purely a UI concern. The logical content should (usually) be unrelated to how it's presented. With the code above, you can retrieve the logical content directly through the `Content` property.

Comment: But if I use this do I have to make the label in the code and then it would be inserted here? If not, how can I change the appearance of the content?

Comment: I used a ContentPresenter because it seemed more adequate, but you can use a Label instead and customize its appearance if you want